# Wrong controller is active when using an external SQL table.

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord

I am working on a back-office app. The apps I am deploying have a model/table of user_messages. The user messages are used to display admin messages from a central app. The idea is that I can use that app to publish messages to the individual apps such as "System will be unavailable from noon to 1 on Friday".

The individual apps use their own schema in the database. for example, the research library would be rl.user_messages etc.

Since I will need to access multiple tables, I set it up so I can access external tables.

```
production:
  adapter: sqlserver
  host: server1
  port: 1435
  database: web
  username: XX
  password: xXX
  schema_search_path: umc

technical_libraries:
  adapter: sqlserver
  host: server1
  port: 1435
  database: XXXX
  username: XX
  password: XXXXXXXX
  schema_search_path: tl
```

The model that lets me connect to the technical library as an external model is

```
class TechnicalLibrary < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'tl_'
  end

  establish_connection "technical_libraries"      # TODO might want to name this to a generic

end

class UserMessage < TechnicalLibrary
  self.table_name = "tl.user_messages"          # for this one, as opposed to the product development, we need to specify the schema.
end
```

My technical Libraries controller is

```
class TechnicalLibrariesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user_messages= TechnicalLibrary::UserMessage.all
  end

  def show
    @technical_library = TechnicalLibrary::UserMessage.first        # TODO HARDWIRED -
  end

  def new
    @technical_library = TechnicalLibrary::UserMessage.new
  end

  def edit
    @technical_library = TechnicalLibrary::UserMessage.find(params[:id])

  end

  def create
    @technical_library = TechnicalLibrary::UserMessageRl.new(technical_library_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @technical_library.save
        format.html { redirect_to @technical_library, notice: 'Technical library was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @technical_library }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @technical_library.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @technical_library.update(technical_library_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @technical_library, notice: 'technical library was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @technical_library }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @technical_library.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end
end


private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_technical_library
  @technical_library = TechnicalLibrary.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def technical_library_params
  params.require(:technical_library).permit(:message, :expires)
end
```

My technical Libraries form is

```
<%= form_for(@technical_library) do |f| %>
  <% if @technical_library.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@technical_library.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this technical_library from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @technical_library.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :message %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :message %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :expires %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :expires %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<hr>
Controller <%= controller_name %> | <%= action_name %>
<hr>
```

The form looks as follows. The submit button seems to be wrong. it is pointing to another model.

[image]

If I click on the submit button, I get an error message as follows. I suspect that the problem lies in inheriting from another model.

```
NameError in UserMessagesController#show
uninitialized constant TechnicalLibrary::UserMessageRl

Rails.root: C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/user_message_console_3

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/user_messages_controller.rb:15:in `show'
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"1"}
```

I had a UserMessage model that I'm probably not going to use since I will connect to the individual application's tables.

```
class UserMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - figured it out. I had to specify the controller and action in the form_for statement.

```
<%= form_for @technical_library, :url => { :controller => "technical_libraries", :action => "update" }, :html => {:method => :post}  do |f| %>
```

That seems to be doing the trick